# Change commas to dots in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am writing an article in a European language, so I included a language package. However, this inclusion changes ALL points to commas in mathmode, because commas are the european decimal separator.

That's fine, but at some point, I want to use a dot as thousandths separator, e.g.

```
$ 63.001,07 $
```

However, if I write a dot, it is converted to a comma anyways. How can I avoid this without disturbing the rest of the document? I am looking for the simplest and easiest solution.

Some of the packages I'm using are:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{ae}
```

Comment: Put ``\mathchardef\period=\mathcode`.`` before `\documentclass` and then use `\period` if you want to have a period.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks a lot, it worked. I encourage you to write it as an answer so I can choose it as best one later.

Comment: The package `ae` is outdated and its usage deprecated. Using a period as thousands separator is a good way to confuse readers; better a thin space.

Comment: Okay, I'll take it into account, but sometimes you have to handle a teamwork in which you cannot decide to remove a package. Also, a period can only confuse readers if they are Anglos, but the document is destined to a reduced number of non-anglo people. We all find the dot much clearer, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\begin{document}
$2.3$
\end{document}
```

> 2.3

For thousands separators, is better a small space. The package `siunitx` can do that automatically, so you can write `$\num{63001. 07}$` as well as `$\num{63001,07}$`  and forget the thousands, but if you insist in a comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
$\num{63001.07}$
\end{document}
```

> 63,001.07

Or inversely, as usual in Spanish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {.}}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
$\num{63001,07}$
\end{document}
```

> 63.001,07